# "ReferenceError: userData is not defined" - How to define userData in separate, helpers function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, backend, user-data

I am a beginner. I want to separate the cryptographic function (encryption.js) from the authentication.js file, but I get an error "ReferenceError: userData is not defined". How to define userData in separate, helpers function?

authentiocation.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const User = require('../models/user');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const encryption = require("../helpers/encryption").encryption;

router.post('/register', (req, res) => { // rejestracja
  const userData = req.body;

  User.findOne({ email: userData.email }, (error, user) => {
   (...)
      else {
        
        encryption(); // <-----------------

        const user = new User({
          firstname: userData.firstname,
          email: userData.email,
          surname: userData.surname,
          password: encrypted
        });
        user.save((error, registeredUser) => {
          if (error) {
            res.status(401).send('Błąd rejestracji!')
          } else {
            const firstname = user.firstname;
            surname = user.surname;
            email = user.email;
            payload = { subject: registeredUser._id };
            token = jwt.sign(payload, 'secretKey');
            res.status(200).send({ token, firstname, surname, email });
          }
```

encryption.js:

```
const express = require('express');

function encryption() {
    const crypto = require('crypto');
    const algorithm = 'aes-192-cbc';
    // Key length is dependent on the algorithm. In this case for aes192, it is
    // 24 bytes (192 bits).
    // Use async `crypto.scrypt()` instead.
    const key = crypto.scryptSync(userData.password, 'salt', 24);
    // Use `crypto.randomBytes()` to generate a random iv instead of the static iv
    // shown here.
    const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0); // Initialization vector.
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
    let encrypted = '';
    cipher.on('readable', () => {
        let chunk;
        while (null !== (chunk = cipher.read())) {
            encrypted += chunk.toString('hex');
        }
    });

    cipher.write('some clear text data');
    cipher.end();
}

module.exports = {
    "encryption": encryption
}
```

Comment: `encryption(userData);` and `function encryption(userData) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it as a param to encryption function (in `encryption.js` file):

```
function encryption(userData) {
    ...
    // at the end:
    return encrypted;
}
```

And then call it like this in `authentiocation.js` (did you mean *authentication* here?):

```
const encrypted = encryption(userData);
```

#### Note:

Edited to address the additional issue mentioned in comment.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know why I didn't think about it :)

Comment: But I still have a problem, this time with "encrypted" in authentiocation.js, because that's not defined there and I get an error "ReferenceError: encrypted is not defined". Do you know how to fix it? :(

Comment: Glad to hear that & good luck on your journey as a programmer